# Text mesh pro copying failed error in unity due to Standard Assets?

Tags: unity-game-engine, runtime-error

I am making a FPS game in unity, for that I imported Character standard Asset in unity. But every time I close unity and again start unity it shows this error-

Copying assembly from 'Temp/Unity.TextMeshPro.Editor.dll' to 'Library/ScriptAssemblies/Unity.TextMeshPro.Editor.dll' failed

But when I tried to re-import Character Standard Asset the error gone.
I have to do this every time I start the project : (

Do Anyone have solution for this ?

Comment: Do you need TextMeshPro?

Comment: No if it gives such error.

Comment: I assume you are using 2018.  The new Package inclusion stuff always causes issues.  Go to `Window`->`Package Manager` and find `Text Mesh Pro` and remove it.  That's what I had to do.

Comment: Thanks It worked I was just working on my game : )

Comment: I'll slap it in as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using 2018. The new Package inclusion stuff always causes issues. Go to `Window->Package Manager` and find `Text Mesh Pro` then remove it. That's what I had to do.

Comment: Would it be OK if we did this removal manually, by simply deleting the TextMeshPro folder in the Packages directory? When I go through the menu option, I get an error message that it is in use and locked, but I cannot figure out where...

Comment: I don't believe you would have any issues doing it that way but using the Package Manager assures all dependencies are cleared up.